# Include a second layout resource in my first one

Tags: android, include, android-layout

Is there a way to include one resource in another (for example a header design in multiple activities' layouts). I know I can add it at run time, can it be done in the XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this in XML. See the  [android docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)
about merge/include

basically you would have 1 layout(`root.xml`) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headingLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/heading_layout" />
  </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

and the `heading_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/titleImg"
          android:src="@drawable/bg_cell"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

so in your `Activity` you would `setContentView(R.layout.root);` which would include the header.

you can also do some cool stuff in addition to this programmatically, such as inserting a layout from xml into a the `root.xml`(after `setContentView();`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, rootLayout);
```

where `rootLayout` is the parent `RelativeLayout` found by id and `R.layout.home` is a layout you wish to add to the root

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. Check out [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/) post for a detailed explanation:

`<include android:id="@+id/my_id" layout="@layout/layout_id" />`